# Running test submodule as main hook

Tags: racket, require

Given this code:

```
#lang racket/base

(module+ test
  (require rackunit rackunit/text-ui)

  (provide suite)

  (define suite
    (test-suite
     "test tests"

     (test-equal? "test string test"
                  "string"
                  "string")))

  (run-tests suite))

;(require 'test)
;(suite)
```

If the last two lines are left commented and the file is run with `raco test test.rkt`, will output

```
raco test: (submod "test.rkt" test)
1 success(es) 0 failure(s) 0 error(s) 1 test(s) run
0
1 test passed
```

Which is expected.

How can I make the file run its tests when it's run just as a script, not by `raco`?

I thought the two commented lines at the end would do what I want: import the submodule and then call the function,

```
(require 'test)
(suite)
```

but instead I get:

```
$ racket test.rkt
require: unknown module
  module name: #<resolved-module-path:'test>
  context...:
   standard-module-name-resolver
```

[Learn Racket in Y Minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/racket/) seems to say that `'test` as a `'symbol` is for submodules, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submodules declared with `module+` and `module*` aren't available for `require` in their containing module because they can depend on their containing module, and cycles in the module dependency graph aren't allowed. (In contrast, submodules declared with `module` can't depend on their containing module, but their containing module can `require` them.)

Try adding a `main` submodule; that should get run when the file is run as a script:

```
(module+ main
  (require (submod ".." test))
  (run-tests suite))
```

BTW, the Racket convention is for the `test` submodule to run the tests, not just to define them. Adding a `main` submodule might make `raco test` stop working for your script; the fix would be to move the `(run-tests suite)` call to the `test` submodule instead.

Comment: Coming from Python where nothing is hidden from anyone, that first paragraph disappoints me. That aside, I'm also used to the Python idiom `if __name__ == "__main__": unittest.main()`, and that's why I want the tests to run when I run the code. I *guess* I'll have to adopt. :c

Comment: You could define the tests in a separate, common submodule, call it `~test` instead of `test`. Then, both `main` and `test` submodules would be identical, defined like in Ryan's answer above, except `require`ing the common submodule `~test` instead of `test`. This way, the tests can be run either via the test runner (`raco`) or directly as a script, and the behavior would be the same. Not sure how idiomatic this is, but seems to be a reasonable solution if this is your goal.